# Visual Studio 2013 connecting to MySQL with UniServer

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

Im writing a project for my college work, it is a commercial till system designed to run off of a database. I have limited time to do this at college however I am having trouble replicating the environment at home.
I am using UniServer Zero XI to run MySQL, this is the same as what I use at college.

I am using this as my connection string:

Dim connection As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;DATABASE=TillSystemDatabase;USER=root;PASSWORD=root;OPTION=3;")

The settings in UniServer ar the same in both locations and so is the database. This works fine on the computers at college but when I bring the code home and try to run it I get the error:
'ERROR[IM002][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

I dont know if there is something wrong with my connection string or im missing a driver(I cant seem to find one that works), None the less It's not important to me how this is solved, I just need to make it work so that I can continue to do my work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install the ODBC driver for MySql? Did you find it with the ODBC  manager (odbcad32.exe)

Comment: @Steve I installed some sort of ODBC driver that I found on someones post who had similar issues, but it didnt do anything, how do I find it with the ODBC manager?